# Selenium Grid Test to be run with 5 instances of one browser on the same node

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I am using selenium grid 2.When I run my selenium test I want this test to be run on one browser 5 times.i.e Suppose I am running a selenium test I want it to be run on 5 instances of firefox browser.

I tried using the below cmd command

```
java -jar E:\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role node -hub http:localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5570 -browser browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5 –maxSession 5
```

But using this command and I am able to create only one browser instance.

Kindly suggest

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26017416/edit) your question to use the question body for your question and the title for a meaningful short description.

Comment: when you look at your grid hub(http:localhost:4444), do you see there only one instance?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
java -jar E:\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role node -hub http:localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5570 -browser "browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5" –maxSessions 5
```

I added speech marks around the -browser args (not sure if this is needed)

and it's `-maxSessions` not `-maxSession`